# In flutter, how to change to relative import from package import?

Tags: flutter, import

After I changed the package name of flutter project, package imports become error because of that changing. And then want to change to relative import from package import. Is there any package or another easy way to fix that all imports. Changing manually is really painful for me because there are a lot of files around 400 dart files in project.

I saw a package `import_path_converter: ^1.0.1`. But that library can't work well and don't change anything.

**Want to change from package import**

`import 'package:xxx_xxx_xxx/modules/splash/splash_screen.dart';`

**To relative import**

`import '../modules/splash/splash_screen.dart';`

Comment: You could use the 'Replace all' functionality in your IDE. Or remove all the old imports and reimport again as relative

Comment: Annn.... some relative imports are different on directory, not consistent. So I think it can't be done by 'Replace all'. Remove all old imports and reimport manually for around 400 files is really painful for me.

Comment: Perhaps a 'replace all' per directory?

Comment: Oh.... thanks !!! I am using android studio and by the using 'replace in files' function.

Answer (score 1):

If you use VSCode, you can try dart-import plugin.

> A simple plugin for VSCode to change all Dart/Flutter imports to
> relative format.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=luanpotter.dart-import

Comment: Sadly I use AS. Anyway thanks for sharing. If found something for android please share.